# Importing meta titles and meta descriptions in Magento 2 from a CSV for multiple products

Tags: magento

I have a store in Magento 2 with a large number of products, and I would like to import meta titles and meta descriptions in bulk, instead of manually entering the information for each product. Is there an efficient way to carry out this import from a CSV file in Magento 2? I would appreciate advice, suggestions, or recommended methods to effectively perform this task and avoid the tedious process of doing it product by product.